# best way to delete file from current directory if it exists in destination directory

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete a file if it exists in a destination directory and if it doesn't exist move the file from Mydir to Desdir.

Please suggest the best way to delete the file from MyDir if it exists in destDir and do not move it to destDir?  Thank you.

Please see the following code:

```
On Error Resume Next
        If Dir(destDir & "\" & strFileName2) = "" Then'//file doesn't exist in destDir
            FileSys.MoveFile Source:=myDir & "\" & strFileName2,   Destination:=destDir & "\" '//move the file
        Else
        '//delete this file from myDir and do not move the file
        'code?
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to delete a file:

```
Kill myDir & "\" & strFileName2    'Kill "C:\test\Test.txt"
```

.

Anther way is using FSO (FileSystemObject)

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub delFile(ByVal fPath As String, ByVal fName As String)

    If Len(Dir(folderID, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then

        If Len(Dir(folderID & fileID)) > 0 Then

            If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then fPath = fPath & "\"

            'Kill fPath & fName

            CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFile fPath & fName

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```